# why doesn't my git post-receive hook seem to work

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, git-post-receive

I have an Amazon EC2 instance that's running linux and has git installed. I setup a git repo with the following command.

```
git init --bare
```

I then cd into the hooks directory and created a post-receive file that has the following bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
```

when I push from my local repo to the server everything seems to go well. I tested this by adding a new file called myfile.html to my project and pushing to the server.  I don't get any errors. However, when I cd to /var/www/mysite directory I don't see the new file that I added, but if I clone the remote repo to a new directory locally I do get all the changes that I pushed to the server.

My thought is that changes are being tracked by git just fine but when the post-receive runs maybe some sort of permissions issue is keeping the files from getting moved and applied to my /var/www/mysite directory ?

Hoping someone can shed some light on what may be happening and how to trouble shoot this.

========================================

So basically the post-receive file needed the following permissions set to make it executable.

```
chmod +x post-receive
```

After doing that I now have an actual permissions issue with where I'm telling git to move the files when they are pushed and the post-receive runs.

My guess is that the post-receive is trying to move the files to /var/www/mysite folder like I'm asking but it now gives me access denied errors when trying to move and change files.

I tried adding sudo to my post-receive script like so

```
    #!/bin/sh
    sudo GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite
    export GIT_WORK_TREE
    sudo git checkout -f
```

doing that gave me the following error when I pushed code.

```
remote: usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
remote: usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
remote:             name|#uid]
remote: usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user
remote:             name] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
remote: usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g
remote:             groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid]
remote:             [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
remote: usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g
remote:             groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] file ...
remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Comment: Ok you are correct Alexey. I set my post-receive to be exacerbate. Now I'm getting some errors. Mostly remote: error: unable to unlink old permission errors. 

I tried running git config core.sharedRepository true on my remote repo. that didn't seem to help.

Comment: I ran the following permissions command chmod -R u+w /var/www/ and that didn't seem to help either.